# Advanced Query mongodb morphia List in List in Object

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

**How to get a list of `Object`, where the `tla` (three letter acronym) of an `LoanboardEmployee` equals the `providedTla` inside the list of `borrowers` inside the list of `ActionStamps` (preferably the last stamp)?**

I have the following classes:

Object:

```
@Id
private String objectCode;
@Embedded
private List<ActionStamp> borrowingHistory;
...
```

ActionStamp (used in Object)

```
@Reference
private LoanboardEmployee responsible;
@Reference
private List<LoanboardEmployee> borrowers;
...
```

LoanboardEmployee (used in ActionStamp)

```
@Id
private short id;
private String tla;
...
```

---

Now I want to find all `Object`, where 1 of the `tla`'s of the `borrowers` in the last `ActionStamp` equals a given tla.

So far i have this:

```
// Select only Object with type Object.class
Query<Object> q = ds.createQuery(Object.class);
// Query the Object only that have a borrowingHistory
q.field("borrowingHistory").exists();
// Query the Object only that have borrowers in the borrowingHistory
q.field("borrowingHistory.borrowers").exists();

// This is where I'm stuck
q.field("borrowingHistory.borrowers.tla").hasThisOne(providedTla);
```

I get the following Error:

```
com.google.code.morphia.query.ValidationException: Can not use dot-notation past 'borrowers' could not be found in 'nl.technolution.loanboard.datamodel.entity.Object' while validating - borrowingHistory.borrowers.tla
```

How should I solve this query?

Comment: Can you post a sample document? I don't know how morphia handles referencing, but the dot notation in mongoDB can only be used with embedded objects, not references.

Comment: @joao What do you mean by sample document? A sample of the mongoDB? 
Refereces in mongoDB are stored like: `responsible (DBRef): { "$ref" : "employees", "$id" : "_id" }`

Comment: Nevertheless, this thread from the mongodb google groups confirms what I just said: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/-ietLwN6xjo

Comment: Thnx for that, I understand. But how to solve this issue then? Get a list with all Objects and All Employees. Than iterate through the TimeStamps and look if the employees (found by id) tla matches the providedTla? But that seems to be a huge operation

Comment: @joao can you give it as an answer (as it is not possible to handle dot notation in MongoDB for references), I'll accept is as the answer